# Reduce Telerik RadScheduler row height in timeline view

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, radscheduler

I used a RadScheduler in timeline view in my ASP.NET project to manage the work schedule of employees. The problem is that [the rows are way too tall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zor0I.png).

Ideally, the height of the rows would be the same height as the activities in it but I can't find how to resize them.

Thanks, lan.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This suggestion seems to get close, but I was not able to get the row headers to also shrink in size.  Did you ever find a solution that worked?

https://www.telerik.com/forums/timeline-row-height-auto-height